# How to remove public/index.php/ from url in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want normal URL like  [www.sample.com/controller](http://www.sample.com/controller) not  [www.sample.com/public/index.php/controller](http://www.sample.com/public/index.php/controller).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My .htaccess  file

Answer (score 23):

Just do

Step 1: In public/ directory, copy index.php and .htaccess to your root project directory.

Step 2: In the root project directory, open index.php and edit the following line:

index.php ->  $pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';

to

index.php => $pathsPath = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution.

Comment: is this really safe?

Comment: Its not recommended. You can rename public to be public_html. The files in public are the "public" files and the rest are not.

Comment: From my understanding, this goes against the entire idea of having the /public directory in the first place. The index.php file is located there for security reasons. The solution provided by Nassim worked for me.

Comment: this answer is not safe you can see that  your .env file is easily accessed by http://yourdomain.tdl/.env best way also protect .env file with help of <Files> tag inside .htaccess .

Answer (score 17):

okay ,  this is how I solved this problem  : 
you need 2 .htaccess files
the first one in root path "/.htaccess" of your project 
the second one in the public folder "public/.htaccess"

and here is the first one "**/.htaccess**"

```
# this is my version (Nassim) of the htaccess file , I use this one in the root directory "/"
# of the project and a second .htaccess in the public directory

DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and the second one (comes with CI installation): "**public/.htaccess**"

```
# I recommend you remove `IfModule`. Because if you need mod_rewrite,
# you don't need `IfModule`. If you don't need it, you don't need this file
# at all.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|doc|data|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Apart from .htaccess file what else you need in the root directory?

Comment: sorry @arunkumar , was so busy to reply , that's all nothing else

Comment: @HeribertoJuárez Great !

Comment: The first .htaccess file (the one in the root dir) wasn't working for me, so I used the one from this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592111/remove-ci4-public-index-php-with-htaccess-rewrite-rule-on-subdomain-folder. The second one I used as you sugested and everything works now :)

Answer (score 14):

go to **app/Config/App.php** and then **public $indexPage = 'index.php';** change to **public $indexPage = '';**

works like charm

Comment: In fact it did! tnks

Comment: Recommended way

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called index.php outside of the public directory and write the command

```
require_once './public/index.php';
```

That's it.

Comment: Does not works wen using multiple controllers.
`pages` would be located at `public/pages`

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up Virtual hosts (if you haven't already), but make sure to point to /public directory (xampp example):

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot "path-to-project/public"
<Directory "path-to-project/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2. Do not touch any .htaccess file in default CI4 distribution
3. Edit app/Config/App.php - $baseURL = 'http://www.example.com/'; $indexPage = '';

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea how you get this `.htaccess`. If you [**download CodeIgniter 4 from here**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4) and you can see [**Htaccess**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/public/.htaccess) file is different what you added.

Since there are many changes in CodeIgniter (1,2,3) to Codeigniter 4, ***htaccess moved to `public/` folder*** which will ***set to document root*** and `.htaccess` which place ***outside will not valid in CI 4***

---

**Correct path to `.htaccess`**

```
public/.htaccess
```

---

**Note:** I just tested `index.php` URL issue and there was no issue like that. worked/loaded fine without `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

**Project Structure codeigniter4**

---

[image: Project Structure codeigniter4]

**If Run project in Xamp show Like this**

---

[image]

---

**Copy public-->index.php to rootfolder-->index.php**
[image]

---

Now run Like this in webbrowser show this like error to solve this
[image]

---

**solution**
[image]

```
    $pathsConfig = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
    to
   $pathsConfig = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

---

Now run

[image]

---

create .htaccess in root folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

[image]

---

Now you can switch your controller name without .htaccess your url must be like this  `http://localhost:8080/payinlinks/index.php/login` 
else  `http://localhost:8080/payinlinks/login` 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1:

- Open the `Your_Project_Folder/app/Config/App.php` file
- Change `$baseURL = 'http://localhost/';` [ ***or*** in-case: `$baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/';` ] ***to*** `$baseURL='http://localhost/Your_Project_Name';`
- Also change `$indexPage = 'index.php';` ***to*** `$indexPage = '';`

[image]

#### Step 2:

- Go into `Your_Project_Folder/public` folder
- Copy the `.htaccess` and `index.php` files from this folder and paste them into your folder's `Your_Project_Folder` root (where a `spark` or `env` file exists).

[image]

#### Step 3:

- Open the `Your_Project_Folder/index.php` file (we've just pasted in project's root)
- Change, `FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';` ***to*** `FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';`

[image]

***All Done!!!***

Answer (score 0):

create a **.htaccess** file in **/public** with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In public/ directory, copy index.php and .htaccess to your root project directory.

Step 2: In the root project directory, open index.php and edit the following line:

change:

### $pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';

### change TO

**($pathsPath = FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IMyF.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /yoursite.com/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "solve" the problem in my hostinger server in one project. After I created a new project with a newer version of codeigniter 4 I realized that I could no longer use the same solution and after hours of research I found a very simple solution.

What I did is I changed the root directory to be the public folder using the .htaccess that is located at the root folder of the project.

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
#RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Using that trick I could load my codeigniter 4 in a live server without any problem. 
Actually, I used this to configure a codeigniter 4 project inside a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

change the index.php =>

```
require realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php') ?: FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

to

```
require realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php') ?: FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/Config/App.php and find `public $indexPage = 'index.php';`.
Remove `index.php` from this public variable and that's it.

Comment: This solution [has already been proposed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66140441/5820258). Stay vigilant when posting answers to old questions...

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above issue removing public/index.php from url then you should following those below steps:

1. Copy the **index.php** and **.htaccess** files from the `public/` directory.
2. Add the files to the root project directory.
3. Change your root project directory **index.php** file `$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php');` into  `$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php');`

Here is the full code of index.php file:

```
// Valid PHP Version?
$minPHPVersion = '7.2';
if (phpversion() < $minPHPVersion)
{
    die("Your PHP version must be {$minPHPVersion} or higher to run CodeIgniter. Current version: " . phpversion());
}
unset($minPHPVersion);

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Location of the Paths config file.
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = realpath(FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php');
// ^^^ Change this if you move your application folder

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * BOOTSTRAP THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * This process sets up the path constants, loads and registers
 * our autoloader, along with Composer's, loads our constants
 * and fires up an environment-specific bootstrapping.
 */

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's directory
chdir(__DIR__);

// Load our paths config file
require $pathsPath;
$paths = new Config\Paths();

// Location of the framework bootstrap file.
$app = require rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '/ ') . '/bootstrap.php';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Now that everything is setup, it's time to actually fire
 * up the engines and make this app do its thang.
 */
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter version 4.2 or above you have to follow `3 steps`:

`1st Step:`
Go to this folder

> App -> config -> app.php

Update `base_url` with `your project folder name` like we do in `Codeigniter 3`
Like this:

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

In case if setup `ci 4` using `composer` then you have this type of `base_url` which you need to change with the above defined `base_url`:

```
public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```

`2nd Step:`
Go to `public` folder and `copy` `index.php` and `.htaccess` files (remember copy them not cut them form here)
Then `paste` them on `root` directory

> > Note: Same as we remove `index.php` in `Codeigniter 3` by creating `.htaccess` file on the root folder and `paste` related code on `.htaccess' file.

`3rd Step:`
Replace `root` folders `.htaccess` file code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then open `root` folders `index.php` file and check line `20` or this line:

```
require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

and remove `../` from it like this:

```
require FCPATH . 'app/Config/Paths.php';
```

> In case you created `css` `js` folder in `public` folder and connected them using `base_url` on `views/header.php` `views/footer.php` or `views/index.php` then might be it occurs problems and don't get these files because of related problems:

> When we use `bootstrap` `cdn` it gives this `syntax` which we made local like this but because of `id="bootstrap-style"` this it occurs problem so remove this form this line:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-style" />
```

> Also form other `css` `linked` file remove this `type="text/css"` or any `id=""` it occures problem.

> The right way to add `css` link is to define `rel="stylesheet"` on link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

> > In my case I got `bootstrap` and `css` related problems.