# Codeigniter 4: Access the application from main folder

Tags: codeigniter-4

My application structure is like:

```
wamp/www
        /project
            /app
            /public
            /system
            /writable
```

I am able to access the application from http://localhost/project/public. However, http://localhost/project shows index of project.

I tried putting .htaccess file in the project folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

It is also not working.

How do I make the application accessible from the project folder.

Comment: this is already answered here i think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376090/how-to-remove-public-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-4

Comment: The rewritebase solution described in the question is taken from the above link. Few other suggestions from the link are also not working.