# Remove CI4 public/index.php with .htaccess rewrite rule on subdomain/folder

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have a subdomain called `test.mysite.com` and I have a CI4 installation inside a folder there called project. So the actual url for the CI4 installation is `test.mysite.com/project/public/index.php`. I want to remove the public/index.php portion from the url but continue to use the public folder to have my files, as they should.

I'm using this .htaccess on the project folder root:

```
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But it's not working. When I access test.mysite.com/project it leads me to a server list of files. I know the .htaccess file is being properly read because when I add an error there it gives me a warning

**EDIT:**
CI4 already comes with an htaccess inside the public folder:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
      RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Comment: And presumably URLs to other pages would look like `/project/<page-url>`? Is CI itself already configured for this URL format? What URLs are you using for your static resources? Do these also omit the `/public` directory?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, the urls to the other pages would look as you said. And yes, CI is ready for this use like this because I have another website with CI4 that is omitting public/index.php from all urls, the difference is that the other website that is working is not on a subdomain and it’s on the root, so it’s not the same htaccess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When I access test.mysite.com/project it leads me to a server list of files

Because your `DirectoryIndex` is set to `/public/index.php` (which presumably does not exist, as the index document is located at `/project/public/index.php`) and directory indexes (mod_autoindex) is presumably enabled (it should be disabled, so that such a request results in a 403 Forbidden).

> the difference is that the other website that is working is not on a subdomain and it’s on the root, so it’s not the same htaccess

I'm not sure why it would be any different?

With the `.htaccess` file in the `/project` subdirectory, arrange your mod_rewrite (and mod_dir) directives like this instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^public/(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The presence of `robots\.txt` and `favicon\.ico` in the first condition implies you are rewriting requests from the document root. Since search engines request `/robots.txt` (in the document root), not `/project/robots.txt` (or `/project/public/robots.txt`). The same applies to `/favicon.ico`. If you are not rewriting these two requests then these two entries are not required.

This also assumes you are linking directly to your static resources using the `public` subdirectory. eg. `/projects/public/images/foo.jpg`. This isn't necessarily desirable since it exposes `/public` in the URL path. Users won't necessarily see this as it's not directly visible in the browser's address bar, but search engines and anyone who views the HTML source / network traffic will see it.

Just to add, that first *condition* (ie. `RewriteCond` directive) is "just" an *opimisation*. If it's set incorrectly, your site will probably work OK and you won't see a difference, except that it will be performing many more filesystem checks than it needs to do.

#### Alternative structure

An alternative approach is to have two `.htaccess` files. A basic `/project/.htaccess` file that simply rewrites *everything* to the `public` subdirectory and a more comprehensive (CI) `.htaccess` file at `/project/public/.htaccess` that actually routes the request to CI. This then allows you to omit `public` from *all* URLs, including URLs to your static resources.

For example:

#### `/project/.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Unconditionally rewrite everything to the "public" subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

#### `/project/public/.htaccess`

The presence of mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file naturally prevent a rewrite loop from the `RewriteRule` directive in the parent directory. (Assuming mod_rewrite inheritance has not been enabled.)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I'm new to modifying htacess files.
I already have a htaccess file in `project/public` from CI with some code. I can edit my answer to show it if you'd like. just adding the first piece of code doesn't seem to work as it's giving me a 403 Forbidden. The alternative version gives me a 404

Comment: Changint the `public` htacces DirectoryIndex to /project/public/index.php like you said fixed it, while also changing the Routes in the CI files to get the default Controller on 'project'. The alternative I can't get to work and I'm not able to access anything else on the website except the homepage. Trying to see what it could be

Answer (score 0):

Working for years with Codeigniter 3 I had this issue too. First I tried the `.htaccess` road but after realizing Codeigniter 3 could also benefit from a more secure structure, I applied the same experience to Codeigniter 4.

The basic idea is to move the whole framework to a folder off the web root. And move the public folder to the root (WEBROOT can also be a subfolder under the public html folder)

```
PRIVATEFOLDER
  \codeigniter: 
     \app
     \vendor
     \writable
WEBROOT
   assets\
   index.php
   .htaccess
```

Then I'll modify index.php (and spark and preload.php if used). This will do in index.php:

```php
// This is the line that might need to be changed... etc
define('ENGINEPATH', 'PRIVATEFOLDER/codeigniter');
require ENGINEPATH . '/app/Config/Paths.php';
```

And /app/Config/Paths.php to this:

```php
namespace Config;
class Paths
{
    public $systemDirectory = ENGINEPATH . '/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system';
    public $appDirectory = ENGINEPATH . '/app';    
    public $writableDirectory = ENGINEPATH .  '/writable';
    public $testsDirectory = ENGINEPATH .  '/tests';
    public $viewDirectory = ENGINEPATH . 'app/Views';
}
```

Now, set the $baseURL to the WEBROOT url and you should be able to navigate without index.php and public, and the app code is protected outside the public folder.

Comment: Why would you say this approach is more secure?

Comment: @FilT maybe I was unclear, it is more secure for CI3, in CI4 with the separated public folder it is more secure. For CI3 this is mentioned in this link: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/index.html#installation-instructions