# removing index.php in ci4 but nothing happen

Tags: codeigniter-4

I changed in App.php

```
public $indexPage = 'index.php';
```

To

```
public $indexPage = '';
```

and

```
public $uriProtocol = 'PATH_INFO';
```

and in `.htaccess`

```
require realpath(FCPATH . ..'app/Config/Paths.php') ?: FCPATH . ..'/app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Comment: Is stackoverflow not going help anyone ? or policy has changed regarding solve to issue.

Comment: Can you share more info about your server setup ?, are you using apache or *nix ?

Comment: using apache server

Comment: Do you have an SSH access to the server ?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the CI user guide... https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/urls.html gives a basic setup for your .htaccess

Comment: Please do not put bounties on questions that already have a number of answers on here. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376090/how-to-remove-public-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter-4 and friends

Comment: i have done all these things but the problem is it is working in both cases withoout and with index.php.anyone can help me please

Comment: are you need to remove index.php from the URL?